# C++ : How to avoid a race condition when comparing 2 integer variables without using a lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 3 shared integer variables which are being written/read in multithreaded code  .
Something like this happens in the shared code . How do I make the thread 2 operation free of data race without relying on a lock ? using a lock would impact my runtime , this is legacy code so I can't really move to std::atomic.

Initially :

```
int var1 = 0, var2 = 0, var3 = 0;
```

later thread 1 does:

```
 __sync_fetch_and_add(&var1, 1);
```

thread: 2

```
 var3 =  var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2 ;
```

thread 3 :

```
 __sync_fetch_and_add(&var2, 1);
```

thread 4

```
 __sync_fetch_and_sub(&var1, 1);
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I want to set var3 based on whatever is greater between var1 and var2 . So if thread2 and thread3 are both in the same critical section , then the following code should be atomic or protected by a lock :  var3 =  var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2 ;
. I dont want to use a lock as that would impact my runtime

Comment: It looks like this is one of those "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" "Well, don't do that then" situations. If you're not willing to guarantee that the values are locked, I don't see how you can guarantee that the code executed by Thread 2 actually gets the current maximum of the two variables. But if another thread is changing one of the values, what does "the current maximum" even mean?

Comment: How do you write to them without a mutex to avoid data races?

Comment: Could you change thread 2 to read and store the values to local variables, then do the max calc, so that the shared globals are only read once?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yeah , that was the only way I could think of doing it . Was wondering if theres any way to make the whole "var3 = var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2" block atomic .

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend moving to std::atomic if at all possible.

Otherwise, implementation will be hardware specific. You can e.g. use x86 XADD instruction with the LOCK prefix for this, it will work on both 32 and 64-bit platforms (since the 486 processor). The code below will work with the GCC compiler:

```
static inline int fetch_and_add(int* variable, int value)
{
    __asm__ volatile("lock; xaddl %0, %1"
      : "+r" (value), "+m" (*variable) // input + output
      : // No input-only
      : "memory"
    );
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code inherently contains a race condition. You want var3 to be the maximum of var1 and var2, but var1 and var2 could change at any moment, so the best you can get is some sort of "var3 is the bigger of whatever I got from var1 and var2 at some point". This race condition is *unavoidable* by the way the problem is defined. You may be able to live with this.

Second, if you're using atomic access to the variables, you also have the problem that you cannot fetch var1 and var2 at the same time, so you could in theory get results that are "impossible" if you look at the individual changes of the variables in some sequence. You can only fix this by putting all access to the variables under a mutex. But most likely, if you can live with the first race condition, you can live with this problem too.

Third, your code contains a *data race* as is, and that's what you need to really avoid. In C++ parlance, a data race is the really bad stuff, the thing that causes undefined behavior, whereas a race condition is higher level and may mess with your invariants, but it won't cause the compiler to assume crazy things about your code.

Now, since you can't work with real atomics, and you also don't want to use a mutex, you cannot technically fully avoid the data race in the C++ standard sense, but sufficiently so for the actual compilers you're using.

What you need to do is use sync-functions to fetch and write everything in thread 2. If you can use the newer __atomic built-ins, use those:

```
int var1value = __atomic_load_n(&var1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
int var2value = __atomic_load_n(&var2, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
int var3value = max(var1value, var2value);
__atomic_store_n(&var3, var3value, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
```

(You may need stricter memory orders depending on what you do.)

The problem with the old __sync built-ins is that they don't provide load and store functions. You can easily emulate load as __sync_fetch_and_add(&var, 0), but I have no idea how you would emulate a plain store.

Comment: Thanks , this is making things much clearer . I now realize there are many things wrong with my approach . That being said , once could probably achieve atomic load by something like this as well right ? 
   __sync_val_compare_and_swap (&var, var3, var3value);